# how to show the notification on certain websites extension page action

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension page action that works on certain websites I want to add a notification whenever the user visits the website specific i'm not satisfied just with the icon in the address bar, how do the notification appears when the user accesses the specific site ?

I have these codes

background, to show the icon in specific sites in the address bar

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

if (~tab.url.indexOf('specificsite.com.br')) {
chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
}

});
```

Code for notification

```
createNotification();
audioNotification();

  function audioNotification(){
  var yourSound = new Audio('alert.mp3');
  yourSound.play();
}

  function createNotification(){
  var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",message: "Your      message",iconUrl: "128.png"}
chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});

//include this line if you want to clear the notification after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear("notificationName",function(){});},10000);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to get it done by content scripts to detect the switch on certain websites, then notify the background page in order to display the notification for that page. Your content script should send a message using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, and the background page should listen using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`:

I created the sample code and tested it works with me:

Content script(myscript.js):

```
if(onCertainWebsitesNeedNotificationAppearTrue) {
    // send message to background script
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {

});
}
```

Background page:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        //alert("good");
        if (request.greeting == "hello")
        createNotification();
    });
function createNotification(){
     var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",message: "Your  message",iconUrl: "128.png"}
     chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});

//include this line if you want to clear the notification after 5 seconds
     setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear("notificationName",function(){});},10000);
}
```

Also keep in mind to register your content script's code and permissions in manifest like:

```
    "permissions": ["notifications"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.certainwebsiteone.com/*", "http://certainwebsitetwo.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: You helped me a lot that's exactly what I'm looking for, but has a little trouble every time I restart the browser notification appears as I do to work only on specific urls?

Comment: Yes. Since "matches" property specifies which pages the content script will be injected into.